# Adding a custom file type in GeoServer

Tags: python, geoserver, geodjango, django

I am trying to add a non-spatial (user-defined) file type, with a `.zzz` file extension, into GeoServer. This file type has no spatial content but as per requirements, I need to store as a Geonode layer. I can easily store this `.zzz` file type as a Geonode document by adding the extension in the as part of the list `ALLOWED_DOCUMENT_TYPES` in the settings.py file.

Is there a way I can change the GeoServer configurationto store these `.zzz` files?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on why you need to store them in GeoServer, or what benefit there would be to storing non-spatial files in GeoServer. But that said if you decide to proceed then you will need to write a new `Datastore` to read these files in and provide the necessary metadata etc for GeoServer to know what to do with them.

There is a [Datastore tutoria](https://docs.geotools.org/maintenance/userguide.old/tutorial/datastore/intro.html)l on the GeoTools site, that will take you through the steps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it is just a client requirement that we store a custom file type (non spatial file) in Geoserver through the Geonode interface.
Is anyone familiar with the Geonode Django framework? If so, is is possible to upload these custom files from geonode and (with the suggested changes) Geonode will accept them? 
The Geonode has several python files involved in the upload process, as per my earlier post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421216/adding-a-new-file-type-as-layer-into-geonode

Comment: GeoServer can only handle file types it can read data from, they don't need to be spatial, can be also tabular. But you won't be able to store a Word file on it, for example. If you're looking for a GeoNode answer I'd recommend you change the title and tags of the question, or better yet, open a different one.